# Add Label to TopAppBar

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

Is possible to add a Label or TextBlock in xaml/c# using CommandBar?

This is my topAppBar

```
<Page.TopAppBar>     
    <CommandBar Visibility="Visible" IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True" >
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Back" x:Name="GoBack" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>     
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Using calibro Micro i need to create my own topbar, is possible to show also text?
or i have to use

```
<AppBar>
```

instead of

```
<CommandBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove icon in appbar style =>

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle2" TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent" Width="100">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,14,0,13" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```